# Include a .html file in Django template that is located in a different directory

Tags: django

Let's say I have the following directory structure

```
|-data
    |-include_this.html
|-app
  |- templates
    |- app 
       |- page.html
```

In `page.html`, I'd like to include the `include_this.html` file contained in the data folder.

I have tried the following:

```
{% include '../data/include_this.html' %}
{% include '../../data/include_this.html' %}
{% include './../data/include_this.html' %}
```

But none of them seem to work, and the second one throws the error: The relative path  points outside the file hierarchy that template is in.

Re: @Edoardo Facchinelli suggestions, I've modified `settings.py` in the following way:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

TEMPLATES = [{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'data')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
}]
```

But the `include_this.html` is still not being recognized.

Running

```
python manage.py shell
from django.conf import settings
print(settings.TEMPLATES[0]['DIRS'])
```

Returns:

`['_templates']`

So it's clearly not adding the data directory specified. What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the path is known to Django, either as an app, or in this case a template dir. One way to do this is explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication#template_directory) that I think is done well, from that page here's a snippet for the `settings.py` file, enabling the `templates` dir.

```
TEMPLATES = [
      {
       ...
       'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
       'APP_DIRS': True,
       ...
```

With other configurations you may need instead the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` variable, but that will depend on your project, mine use the method in the snippet above.

Once set up, Django will know what `data` means and you should be able to reference it like so:

```
{% include 'data/papercups.html' %}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm having a little trouble understanding what should go in DIRS. I've added: `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` and `TEMPLATES = [{
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'data')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
}]` but the papercups file is still not being referenced. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try opening the shell (`python manage.py shell`), and check that the paths are the correct ones: `from django.conf import settings`  then `print(settings.TEMPLATES[0]['DIRS'])`. This should show the actual path that Django will try.